# problem regarding karnaugh map

Tags: digital-logic, karnaugh-map

[image]

I can't understand how decimal designation differ by power of 2??

Comment: never use decimal number representation when dealing with karnaugh maps

Answer (score 1):

If you, instead of decimal, write the same representation in binary, you'll find that "switching a single bit" means switching a binary position – and these positions are powers of two, by definition of how binary numbers are base-2.